# List<Class>() vs List<Class>(0)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Is there any difference between executing these two lines of code:

```
IList<Class> list = new List<Class>();
```

and

```
IList<Class> list = new List<Class>(0);
```

I've been told that first, capacity-less constructor is more effective because it allocates less memory compared to constructor with 0 capacity. I've searched MSDN, and it is written there that default capacity of the List is 0 anyways and I do not see any logic in this...

Can anybody confirm or deny this theory?

Comment: did you have a look at the reference source?! http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Comment: "_I've been told first_" that `x = a`, then "_I've searched MSDN_" and it said `x = b`. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually answer the question pretty easily with the help of http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

```
public List() {
  _items = _emptyArray;
}
```

vs

```
public List(int capacity) {
  if (capacity < 0) ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.capacity, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum);
  Contract.EndContractBlock();

  if (capacity == 0)
     _items = _emptyArray;
  else
    _items = new T[capacity];
}
```

As you can see for yourself: If no initial capacity is supplied (`ctor()`) the internal `_items` array is set to `_emptyArray`, which is the same behavior for `ctor(0)`. This looks like an internal optimization for all the `ctor(0)`-calls to avoid (superfluous) allocations of an empty array.

In the end, neither of the above ctor-calls is really memory-effective compared to a real initial capacity. This is the nature of the very datastructure, which dynamically extends accordingly. So, whenever you know the real capacity upfront, you should call `ctor(capacity)` to avoid the resizing (which is implemented [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,eb66b6616c6fd4ef) and called on every write).

Comment: So, in a nutshell, it makes no difference whatsoever (with the exception of a few additional checks, which are completely negligible).

Comment: for the same in core-clr: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs

Comment: Hm. Actually, your research shows that `new List()` is slightly faster than `new List(0)` due to skipping argument checks. If someone is really nit-picking, then one could say that `List()` takes up less space on the stack, so it "uses less memory".. but I wouldn't like to discuss it further with a person in such a bad mood

Comment: @quetzalcoatl nah fam, no bad mood :) I am not so sure for the additional memory overhead, as there's only allocs for the exception if out of range ... should benchmark that though, as strings are tricky as fun :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl but yep, you got a point there for *faster*, as `ctor()` has no check for `capacity` :) Anyway, I'd say that the initial build-up does not compare to the dynamic resizing that will occur after `.Add`...